# How to passing an id into controller with laravel and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

i have problem maybe it is a dumb problem. i want passing an `$id` from jquery `$.get()` into controller. the problem is, the `$id` did not send or maybe catched.

i've tried this :

note : also i have tried to use php echo instead `{{$cari->id}}`

```
$.get("/showProductTool/{{  $cari->id }}"), function(data, status){
        $('#tool').html(data);
        $.each($('.itemTools'), function(index, value){     
            $( "#itemTools"+index).draggable({
            revert:true,
            zIndex: 100,
            });
        }); 
  });
```

and in controller :

```
public function showTools($id){
    $cari = Product::findOrFail($id);
}
```

and in routes :

```
Route::get('/showProductTool/{id}', 'ProductController@showTools');
```

======here's my code======

Routes :

```
Route::get('/showProductTool/{id}', 'ProductController@showTools');
```

Controller :
1. to send an $id to the view, i use :

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $cari = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();
     if (empty($cari)) {
        abort(404);
    }return view('myView', compact('cari'));
}
```

2. and to catched the `$id` from jquery `$.get()`:

   `public function showProduct($id){
   $cari = Product::findOrFail($id);
   }`

Comment: any console errors?, what are you returning for showTools?

Comment: nope. there is not error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what the error was, but I'm guessing that the url wasn't translating correctly from `$.get` into your routes, as it was possibly missing the initial site prefix.  Give the below a try, this will add the prefix and sit the id correctly into your route:

```
$.get('{{url("showProductTool/$cari->id")}}'), function(data, status){ ... etc }
```